# What's the meaning of static variables in an implementation of an interface?

Tags: objective-c, variables, static, static-variables

I don't quite understand static variables when defined in the implementation of an interface. In methods I do understand how they differ from local variables, but not when defined directly in an implementation.

Look at these examples. What difference do these two make practically?

```
#include "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
int myInt;
...
@end
```

And:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
static int myInt;
...
@end
```

`myInt` is in both cases visible to all the methods, and if I interpreted a test I ran correctly, `myInt` will in both cases be the same variable for different instances of the class.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4965145/654870

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The 'static' keyword in that context is the same as it would be in plain C: it limits the scope of myInt to the current file.

Comment: Also, defining a non-local variable inside @implementation is no different from defining it outside.

Comment: But does this really make any difference for definitions in implementation files? They're not included anyways.

Comment: Assume you declared int Varibale; in two different implementation files. You will get errors at build time, because of duplicate symbols.

Comment: Does this mean that it acts as the "private" access modifier?

Comment: No. The 'private' keyword in C++ just adds compiler-enforced restrictions on who can access a variable or method. 'static' scopes it to the just the file it's in, which is very different.

Comment: I would replace the words "the current file" with "the compilation unit". `static`s can be `#import`ed into multiple files, but I should mention that doing so is probably (always?) a bad idea, and a misuse of `static`.

Comment: My guess is that many people who don't know what static is probably also don't know what a compilation unit is, so I simplified slightly.

Answer (score 93):

Unfortunately, it has different effects depending on where you use it.

**Static Functions:**
By default, all functions have a global scope. The static specifier lets you limit the function’s scope to the current file.

**Static Local Variables:**
When you use the static modifier on a local variable, the function “remembers” its value across invocations. For example, the currentCount variable in the following snippet never gets reset, so instead of storing the count in a variable inside of main(), we can let countByTwo() do the recording for us.

```
// main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int countByTwo() {
    static int currentCount = 0;
    currentCount += 2;
    return currentCount;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%d", countByTwo());    // 2
        NSLog(@"%d", countByTwo());    // 4
        NSLog(@"%d", countByTwo());    // 6
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This use of the static keyword does not affect the scope of local variables.
Read more about the [static keyword](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/functions.html).

Comment: The static keyword will enforce its line to be executed ONLY once for the entire application runtime--regardless of the number of invocations!

Comment: Where in memory is the static variable "currentCount" stored? It can't be in countByTwo's frame because that frame is deallocated when the function ends. So where is it stored?

Comment: @Enrique in the same data/bss areas that the other "global" variables live, it's just the scope that is local

Answer (score 24):

"In both C and Objective-C, a static variable is a variable that is allocated for the entire lifetime of a program. This is in contrast to automatic variables, whose lifetime exists during a single function call; and dynamically-allocated variables like objects, which can be released from memory when no longer used. More simply put, a static variable's value is maintained throughout all function/method calls. When declared outside of a function, a static variable is visible to everything within the file in which it is declared; when declared inside a function or method, it is visible only within that function or method, but the value is retained between calls."

Check out the complete explanation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965145/951349

Answer (score 18):

From Apple's "The Objective-C Programming Language":  "Declaring a variable *static* limits its scope to just the class -- and to just the part of the class that's implemented in the file. (Thus unlike instance variables, static variables cannot be inherited by, or directly manipulated by, subclasses)."