# static variables in Objective-C - what do they do?

Tags: objective-c, static, var

I've seen a few posts discussing what a static variable is and I think I get it - but I'd love to quickly write (or find) a program that utilizes both a regular and a static variable, side by side, and see how/when they operate differently. Some quick n dirty code, maybe two int vars and a couple of NSLog tracking statements just to see HOW they're different.

Anybody got any tips/ideas/code out there that would illustrate how a static var differs from a regular one?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Because Objective-C simply extends C:

In both C and Objective-C, a *static* variable is a variable that is allocated for the entire lifetime of a program. This is in contrast to *automatic* variables, whose lifetime exists during a single function call; and dynamically-allocated variables like objects, which can be released from memory when no longer used. More simply put, a static variable's value is maintained throughout all function/method calls. When declared outside of a function, a static variable is visible to everything within the file in which it is declared; when declared inside a function or method, it is visible only within that function or method, but the value is retained between calls.

Say you have this:

```
int f(void)
{
    int i = 5;
    i += 10;
    return i;
}
```

Every call to `f()` will return the value `15`.

Now say you have this:

```
int g(void)
{
    static int i = 5;
    i += 10;
    return i;
}
```

The first time `g()` is called, the value `15` will be returned. The second time, `25` will be returned, as `i` maintained its value of `15` and then incremented itself by `10`. The third call, `35` will be returned. And so on.

In the context of Objective-C classes, static variables are often used to mimic *class variables*, as Objective-C does not have class variables (other languages, such as Java, do). For instance, say you want to lazily initialize an object, and only return that object. You might see this:

```
static MyObject *obj = nil;

@implementation MyObject

+ (id)sharedObject
{
    if (obj == nil) obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    return obj;
}

@end
```

`obj` will be initialized the first time `classObject` is called; subsequent invocations of `classObject` will return the same object. You could check this by logging the address of the object:

```
NSLog(@"obj is at %p", [MyObject sharedObject]);
NSLog(@"obj is at %p", [MyObject sharedObject]);    // Will print the same address both times
```

Furthermore, `obj` will be visible to all methods in `MyObject`.

This technique is used to implemented singleton classes in Objective-C as well.

> **Note** that putting "static" variables inside methods is not thread-safe, at least not in all compilers.
>
> And even in those compilers where it's safe, it's a little expensive (because of hidden auto locking, yes, it uses something like a "global mutex" without asking the developer).

Comment: Very good explanation - though it seems like the naming convention is backwards! :-)  What I mean is this: the word STATIC means something that is NOT changing, and yet its the static variable - judging by your example of "int f(void)" vs. "int g(void) - is the one whose value seems to constantly change - it isn't static at all!

Comment: come to think of it, why is it called "static" then? what IS static about it?

Comment: Coming from Java, that syntax of having static int i = 5; inside a method always throws me off. I always think of an assignment inside a method as assigning a new value 5 to i.

Comment: Another note : If the variable is defined as static in a header file then each implementation file (.m) that includes the header file gets it's own copy of that variable.

Comment: In `g()`, what exactly happens on that first line (`static int i = 5;`) on the second (and subsequent) calls? Does the compiler simply ignore the assignments that are contained within subsequent declarations of a static variable?

Comment: @TimArnold: It essentially gets allocated once, just like a top-level `static` variable, except that `i` is scoped to `g()`.

Comment: @TimArnold If you put a break point there you'll see it never returns to that line to reset it for the program's life.

Comment: Even if I remove the "static" word, it logs the same memory addresses and in that case also, obj will be available to whole MyObject class. Then what is the difference here?

Comment: *"as Objective-C does not have class variables"* - class properties were added to Objective-C years ago. While not exactly the same as class variables, class properties can help eliminate the need to use static file variables.

Answer (score 2):

static works mostly like in C.

1. It can either initialize a variable only once.
2. Declaring a variable static in a file above `@implementation`block will be available for the whole file only.

Answer (score 1):

"static" refers more to the attributes of the variable (who what where) rather than just the value. Unlike other languages where it refers exclusively to the value.

- **Sticky**

It's like pinning the var to a specific location, be it inside a function or in the implementation.

- **Private**

It has similar attributes to a "private" var in that it's not visible to sibling or parents, but children can access.

- **Classy**

It is a declaration with default value. Like in other languages where you define vars within a class and assign their "default" value:

`private int myNumber = 3;`

This gives us "class-like" variables within functions. Declare them once, then as the function manipulates the value, the value is retained. The next time the function is called, the value will be the same as it was after the previous "cycle", just like you would expect a class variable's value to remain after manipulation.