# stringByAppendingString on same object

Tags: objective-c

i want to ask a question on `NSString`, the question is if

```
NSString str = @"Hello";
str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"World"];
```

if we `NSLog` the `str` we would get an output - `HelloWorld`!

So my question is if `str` is `NSString` class variable an its an static one (which can not be changed once it is defined) then how can we able to change  it, (Note that I have used same `NSString` object `str`).

Comment: you are basically reassigning `str`. like `int i = 0` ... `i = i+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared the string as static, but `NSString` is immutable. You are creating a new string and replacing `str`. Many Obj-C classes have a mutable type, so if you intended to modify your string as in this example, you might want something more like:

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello"];
[str appendString:@" World"];
```

Note, @"Hello" is a `NSString`, so attempting to initialize a `NSMutableString` using that syntax would result in an error.

Comment: Thanks! Got my answer, actually it was asked me in an interview, but i couldn't be able to answer it correctly at that time, i can explain it more clearly if someone ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, static variables can be changed once they are defined. Static variables are simply maintained throughout all function/instance calls. You can find a more detailed explanation here [static variables in Objective-C - what do they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965048/static-variables-in-objective-c-what-do-they-do). So the result would be the same. If the variable were defined as const (which cannot be changed) then you would get a compiler error. Generally speaking, the best way to figure these types of things out is to just try them on your own. If it's just a matter of writing a couple lines of code, or changing a keyword, what does it hurt?

Comment: This answer kind of misses the point, since the OP is mistaken about having a static variable.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. I understood it as "if str were declared static, how do you change it's value?"