# How can I save global variables in iOS development?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an iOS application with several controllers, each with their own xib files.

How do I set a global variable with scope that spans all controllers? Should I use `NSUserDefaults` and retrieve data for each view every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` are for things that require persistance, i.e. you are planning on storing them between app starts. For temporary variables, consider using a **singleton instance**, such as the `MySingleton` class illustrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/145164/108574 .

When you have this class, put your temporary variables as `property` of this class for easy access. And when you need to access it, just call `[MySingleton sharedSingleton].variable`.

Also check here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html for more information.

Answer (score 10):

In general, you want to avoid using globals. If you need access to data that must be shared, there are two common approaches.

**Put the values in your AppDelegate.**

If you have only one or two shared values, the AppDelegate is an easy way to place shared content.

The AppDelegate can be accessed from your controllers as such:

```
FooApp* appDelegate = (FooApp*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Where `FooApp` is the name of your application Class.

**Create a singleton class.**

Polluting your AppDelegate with lots of shared values isn't ideal, and/or if you want these values to persist from session to session, creating a [Singleton](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) class that is backed by `NSUserDefaults`
is another way to share values across instances.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your precise needs you could learn about and use the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern to create a sort of database object that can be shared across all views. Read about iOS Singletons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc).

This is how I accomplished what you are looking for in my iOS App.