# Duplicates in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I've tried to build a modern way of saving data in Core Data with using `NSManagedDocument`. Everything is working fine except that if I restart the app (terminate it and run it again) I will get duplicated entities in my database and sometimes the app crashes with error:

> This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot
>   perform a save operation.

I think there is something going on in differents threads and making trouble but I can`t figure out what I have to change. Hopefully one of you could help me.

My class called `Database` has this implementation

```
+ (Database *)sharedDatabase
{
static Database *sharedInstance;
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default Database"];
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    sharedInstance.isCreating = NO;
    sharedInstance.isOpening = NO;
});
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[sharedInstance.fileURL path]]) {
    if (!sharedInstance.isCreating) {
        sharedInstance.isCreating = YES;
        [sharedInstance saveToURL:sharedInstance.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            sharedInstance.isCreating = NO;
        }];
    }
} else if(sharedInstance.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
    if (!sharedInstance.isOpening) {
        sharedInstance.isOpening = YES;
        [sharedInstance openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            sharedInstance.isOpening = NO;
        }];
    }
}
return sharedInstance;
}
```

then I've created a data model with one entity called `Book`. For keeping it simple it has just an `isbn` (of type `NSString`) as attribute.
A category `Create` for the `NSManagedObject` subclass `Book` (Xcode auto-generated subclass) has the following implementation to check if an ISBN already exists in the database or not. This should return a newly created entity or the existing one and return nil when some error occurs like having 2 books with the same ISBN.

```
+(Book *) bookWithISBN:(NSString *)isbn inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
Book *book;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Book"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isbn LIKE %@", isbn];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"isbn" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

NSError *error;
NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (!matches || (matches.count > 1)) {
    return nil;
} else if(matches.count == 0){
    book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    book.isbn = isbn;
}else{
    book = [matches lastObject];
}
return book;
}
```

So now if I invoke this method by calling `[Book bookWithISBN:@"1234567890" inManagedObjectContext:[Database sharedDatabase].managedObjectContext]` the first time I run the application it will create an entity in my database. If I terminate the app and run it again it creates the same entity one more time. And the second time I terminate and run it again it returns `nil` (like it should because there are 2 books with the same ISBN).

I am using ARC in this project.

**Possible solution**:

I have been experimenting some hours now and untill now it seems to work if I dont subclass `UIManagedDocument` and instead make a class that inherits from `NSObject` and contains an `UIManagedDocument`. Does somebody know is that really is the right solution? because I think it should be possible to subclass `UIManagedDocument`.

Comment: I think i found a solution myself. if i replace = with LIKE when setting the requests predicate it works in my example. I`ll test it in my real app which is a lot more complicated and will give a response tomorrow. I just dont get why '=' would be working correct in case of second 're-run'

Comment: Did you use "=" or "==" originally?

Comment: i used single '=' originally

Comment: You should be using "==" for comparisons. Give it a try.

Comment: now after about 5 tries even LIKE did stop working. I think the problem is somehow related to the managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion won't solve your immediate problem, but i'll put it out there anyway. I used to use coreData in raw form like you do until I discovered MagicalRecord. It is awesome. You should check it out. https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

The benefit is that it packages all CoreData code into neat digestible code. And it takes care of managing context relationships in threads.

Comment: I actually tried this for a year ago or more and thought that it was really complicating but maybe today i got a better understanding for all terms

Answer (score 0):

All the instantiation code must reside within the dispatch_once block. You want to ensure that you open the document only once.

This link shows that all the instantiation code must be within the dispatch_once block.

[How do I implement an Objective-C singleton that is compatible with ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc)

Comment: I tried to include the opening and creating operation into the dispatch_once block with no change