# Best approach for storing single BOOL global data value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need some advice about best practice of developing iOS app design

Here's what I'm dealing with: when iOS device looses internet connection (or doesn't have one and figuring that out) I want my app to go to some sort of offline mode, i.e. firing some event, sending some NSNotifications, m.b. showing some sort of alert etc. Accordingly, when iOS device gets it's connection back I want the oposite thing - move my app to some sort of online mode.

So, what I want is to have ability to access app's mode (i.e. to check whether app is online or offline) from within some of my ViewControllers. I'm thinking of two methods of storing app's state:

1) Have some AppDelegate's property and access it from anywhere via my AppDelegate. AFAIK, that's a wrong approach, because AppDelegate is not supposed to be used as global object for application, but for doing launch initialization and controlling application's state changes.

2) Store this information on Model level. But I have no idea what am I supposed to use on Model level for such purpose. I don't think using Core Data or NSUserDefaults is a good idea, because I don't want this property to be persistent, I need it only during current application running. And apart from Core Data and NSUserDefaults I don't actually know any other Model level techniques.

I don't include any code examples, because it's mostly a theoretical question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use singleton pattern and store the variable as a property

for example

```
@interface GlobalData : NSObject

@property BOOL connectionAvailable;

+ (GlobalData *)sharedInstance;

@end

@implementation

+ (GlobalData *)sharedInstance {
    static GlobalData *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[GlobalData alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end

// --- in some method
[GlobalData sharedInstance].connectionAvailable = /* connection state */;

// --- in some other method
BOOL connectionAvailable = [GlobalData sharedInstance].connectionAvailable;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second approach works best. You surely don't need any persistence a property indicating the internet connection. A good thing to do is having your Model be a singleton class, that exposes a readonly `BOOL` property for the internet connection and your view controllers can subscribe to its changes via key-value observing. Your model can also implement internally the `Reachability` class for updating the internet connection status.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Apple's Reachability class. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I created a category on the Reachability class to add a sharedInstance singleton that allows you to check the state of the internet connection. I use this in all my apps.

Here's how you do singletons:

[How do I implement an Objective-C singleton that is compatible with ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc)

Comment: Yes, I'm using this class. In my case I have a need to also move my application to offline mode manually, i.e. when some error happens on backend. But anyway, that's seems like a good solution for trivial cases.