# Static attribute, Static Class, Singleton Pattern

Tags: objective-c

I have 3 class.

- Class A contains :

  1. A static variable "dataX".
  2. A setter method to set the data.
  3. A getter method to return the data value.
- Class B
- Class C.

the flow is as follows:

The Class B instanciates the Class A and initialize the variable "dataX" with the setter method.

Afterwards, the class C instantiates the Class A in the viewDidLoad method and gets the value of the static variable.

But even if the variable in Class A is static, the variable is always null.

I guess that I need to put the Singleton Pattern with a static Class A and not simply a static attribute.

What is the syntax to specify a Class as Static?

The code below:

```
//  HandleMessage.h

@interface HandleMessage : NSObject
@property *NSString nameFile;

// Getter
- (NSString *)getNameFile;

// Setter
- (void)setNameFile: (NSString *) value;

@end
```

And:

```
//  HandleMessage.m

#import "HandleMessage.h"

@implementation HandleMessage

static nameFile;

@synthesize nameFile ;

// Getter definition
- (NSString *)getNameFile{
    return nameFile;
}

// Setter definition
- (void)setNameFile: (NSString *) value{
    nameFile = value;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how you declared the static variable, and how you coded the setter and getter.

Comment: @Hot Licks , Post edited.

Comment: This question isn't related to Xcode tag

Comment: It isn't either to iOS, it's just pure Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate another instance of a class of course this instance's value is null.

You can work with singletons or store your data elsewhere (if you want to keep data between app starts in your user defaults using NSUserdefaults)

Comment: I just want to avoid Global Data. 
Thx you for NSUserdefaults, I will look closely how it is used.

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by "Class as Static"??

you can use singleton pattern, which i described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15107876/642626)

or using class method

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA

+ (void)setData:(int)data;
+ (int)getData;

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
static int sData;

@implementation ClassA

+ (void)setData:(int)data {
    sData = data;
}

+ (int)getData {
    return data;
}

@end
```

Comment: A static Class is an Interface with attributes. We can use it without instantiation needed.

Comment: Yes, I also followed this way but when you define your variable  data through setter in a class B and you want to get this same variable in a Class C, the variable is null at this moment because you instantiate a new object of Class A in Class C.

Do you see?