# Macros like [self class]

Tags: objective-c, macros

I want create macros, which return self class.

**MyCustomClass.m**:

```
static MyCustomClass *_instance = nil;  //not suitable
static [self class]  *_instance = nil;  //incorrect, but want like this
static SELF_CLASS    *_instance = nil;  //target
```

How can create macros like this:

```
#define SELF_CLASS ...?...
```

Comment: May be you can get some ideas from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16976902/137350

Comment: How about `instancetype` or `id`?