# Have multiple instances of a class point to one object @property

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, properties

I will try to make this question as understandable as possible. I am implementing core data in my app, and I need to access the `NSManagedObjectContext` from around 10,000 different instances of a class (this class extends `UIView`). The Core Data stores what is displayed on these instances and the class builds it.

Everything that I have found so far uses View Controllers, of which you only have one instance, so you can just `alloc init` the VC in `AppDelegate`, set an `@property` for `NSManagedObjectContext` and be on your way. This does not work for my program.

What I want to do is have many instances of my `CoreDataHelper` class (which I will `alloc init` in the class that I have around 10,000 instances of, which all have a property pointing to the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. Is this a possible way to do it or will I have to make my program less flexible by moving all of the code to create the 10,000 different objects to the `View Controller`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put your `NSManagedObjectContext` in a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc) and all your instances can access the single class.

Comment: So if my NSManagedObjectContext is a singleton I just reference that singleton when I am initializing my data?

Comment: You can provide a property on your singleton to access the `NSManagedObjectContext` it contains. Then it can be accessed from any class in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you get your managed object context from a singleton or from your app delegate (where presumably you the core data stack is set up by default).

To follow the pattern suggested by Apple with view controllers, do the exact same thing with your views: give them a `@property` of type `NSManagedObjectContext` and set it during initialization. Seems straight forward enough.

The advantage of the singleton is that you do not even need the property on your view but can call the singleton instead. But why go there? From your comments I understand that you do not really know how a singleton works. You don't need it. Go with the class property solution.

One more caveat: with your setup, **you are seriously braking the MVC architecture** by giving the views access to your data. Instead, you should indeed have a **view controller** do this and then populate your views with the retrieved data. I do not think that there is a compelling reason to deviate from this principle.